# How to connect to a website using Telnet in Windows 10?

Tags: html, windows, http, telnet

I am learning web development on Udacity.com. I am trying to connect to a website using telnet with the following command in the command prompt (I installed telnet first):
`telnet www.udacity.com 80`

After that I just get a blank screen with a cursor blinking. As I type, the cursor moves forward but I don't see any letters.
I typed `GET / HTTP/1.0` but I didn't see any letters on the screen. And if I press enter after that, the screen is still blank.

I am using windows 10 64 bit version.

**Edit 1:**
I tried writing in the following:

```
telnet iana.org 80 
GET /domains/example HTTP/1.0
Host: iana.org
```

I could not see all of the above written but the cursor kept moving forward. When I hit enter twice, I get the expected results. But I cannot see the letters initially as I type them.

Comment: Can you tell why you need to connect with telnet to a server? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am supposed to answer a question on udacity about the information(the headers) that I receive from the server when I make a GET request.

Comment: Why not open Chrome / Firefox / Internet explorer and press F12. Go to network tab and navigate to the website

Comment: I am sorry but I did not understand anything of what you said. I tried doing what you said but could not see anything I could understand. This is my first day with coding so I you will have to walk me through it.

Comment: Why not ask your teachers?

Comment: the course was developed in 2012 by udacity. I have asked a question there as well but I havent received any response yet.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open you favorite browser (I prefer Google Chrome)
2. Go to your website http://udacity.com
3. Press `F12`
4. Go to the `Network tab` (check out this website for information about this tab https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network)
5. And hit `Ctrl + F5`

Now you see all the information about the requests that will be send from and received on your computer. By clicking on one of those requests you will see some information about it. Like header information etc....

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, but I will check it out. I could not understand what started happening after I hit ctrl+f5.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, but I will check it out. I could not understand what started happening after I hit ctrl+f5. Random lines with different colors started appearing with 1000ms 2000ms and so on till 5000ms on the X axis.

Comment: Could you tell me about the telnet method? And why do I not see any letters when I am typing? I put in the command: GET / HTTP/1.0 <br> Host: www.example.com and then hit enter twice ( even though I was not able to see what I was typing). After that telnet responded as it should and I got what I was looking for. But why cant I see the letters in the beginning. Thanks so much for bearing with me.

Comment: please take a look at the following site https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Check_TCP_Port_80_%28http%29_with_telnet this site will tell you how to connect. If you do not see anything on your screen try disabling your firewall.